# unknown directive "server" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:4

Tags: nginx

With nginx/0.7.65 I'm getting this error on line 4. Why doesn't it recognize `server`?

```
#### CHAT_FRONT ####

server {
  listen 7000 default deferred;
  server_name example.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/chat_front/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}

#### CHAT_STORE ####

server {
  listen 7002 default deferred;
  server_name store.example.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/chat_store/current/public;

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}

#### LOGIN ####

server {
  listen 7004 default deferred;
  server_name login.example.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/login/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}

#### PERMISSIONS ####

server {
  listen 7006 default deferred;
  server_name permissions.example.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/permissions/current/public;

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}

#### SEARCH ####

server {
  listen 7008 default deferred;
  server_name search.example.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/search/current/public;

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}

#### ANALYTICS ####

server {
  listen 7010 default deferred;
  server_name analytics.example.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/analytics/current/public;

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `server` directive must be contained in the context of `http` module. Additionally you are missing top-level events module, which has one obligatory setting, and a bunch of stanzas which are to be in the http module of your config. While [nginx documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample) is not particularly helpful on creating config from scratch, there are [working examples](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration) there.

Source: [nginx documentation on server directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server)

Comment: Are there other settings inside of the http directive that I'll have to make or just wrap it?

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample try this. Events module is used to tell nginx how to deal with connections (for example, how many connections a worker can keep concurrently - in fact, it's the only obligatory stanza from `events`). A little bit more help can be found on http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration

Comment: @Chris I know it's old but to solve `no "events" section in configuration` you should add `events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}` into your nginx.conf.

Answer (score 11):

Adding a top level entry got around the problem:

```
events {  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to adjust line endings and the encoding of your configuration file. In my case ANSI encoding and possibly "Linux style" line endings (only `LF` symbols, **not** both `CR` and `LF` symbols) were required.

I know it is a rather old question. However the recommendation of the accepted answer (that the `server` directive must be contained in the context of `http` module) might confuse because there are a lot of examples (on the *Nginx* website also and in [this *Microsoft* guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.2)) where the `server` directive is **not** contained in the context of `http` module.

Possibly the answer of **sd z** ("I rewrote the *.conf file and it worked") comes from the same reason: there was a **.config** file with incorrect encoding or line endings which was corrected after the file has been rewrited.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue similar to Hoborg, whose comment pointed me in the right direction. In my case, I had copy and pasted a config from a [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243563/try-files-not-working-with-nginx-docker-image) to use for a docker container hosting an Angular app. This was the default config plus one extra line. However, when I pasted, there were a few extra characters included at the beginning of the paste (EF BB BF). The IDE I was using (visual studio) did not display anything to indicate these extra bytes, so it wasn't apparent that they existed. Removing these extra bytes resolved the issue, which I did using a hex editor (HxD) because it was convenient at the time. The windows style line endings did not seem to be an issue in my case.

The default config had `server` as the outermost directive, so the top answer and error message was indeed confusing. That remained the same as it was originally in my case, and the original file (without the 3 extra bytes) had not thrown the error.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the *.conf file and it worked.